# Select nonexisting attributes

Tags: sql, join, relation

I've 3 tables named products, attributes and a relation table product_attributes. You can see them with example entries below.

```
products
id| product_name
1 | Product 1
2 | Product 2
```

attributes
id| attribute
1 | length
2 | width
3 | height
4 | weight
5 | color

product_attributes
id| product_id| attribute_id| value
1 | 1         | 1           | 120
2 | 1         | 2           | 60
3 | 2         | 1           | 100
4 | 2         | 3           | 40
5 | 2         | 5           | red

To show Product Details:

**Product 1**
Length: 120
Width: 60

Unlinked attributes for Product 1:
*Height, weight, color*

**Product 2**
Length: 100
Height: 40
Color: Red

Unlinked attributes for Product 2:
*Width, Weight*

The thing I want to do is mainly, when i select a product, get unlinked attributes.
For example, when I select Product 1, sql will return
*Height, weight, color*

I know it can be done with PHP but also know it can be done with SQL, too. 
I just wanted to brainstorm a bit.

How it can be done with SQL? Especially in MySQL?

Comment: `For example, when I select Product 1, sql will return Height, weight, color` wrong. Color (attribute_id==5) is not present in table product_attributes for product_id==1 EDIT: you want a left join on the EAV-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch non-existing attributes for a specified product, i think you should use this query,
note that, without inner select query this query will fetch attributes whichs are not used for any of products.

```
SELECT attribute FROM attributes a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_attributes pa WHERE pa.product_id = 1 ) pa ON a.id = pa.id 
WHERE pa.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the best way, but it should work.

```
SELECT attribute FROM attributes
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM product_attributes
    WHERE product_id = '1')
```